# Where should I put general utility functions which will be used by multiple Vue.js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Usually I create the function in the component which is gonna use the function, however, I'm starting to have the need to use a certain function in 2 or more components, which means that right now I would have to copy and place it in the other components. This is obviously less than optimal, so I am wondering where should I place those functions. To show you what I mean by general utility functions I'll add one here:

```
winrate(wins, losses) {
    let games = wins + losses
    return Math.round(wins * 100 / games) + '%'
}
```

Nothing special, it just takes wins and losses and then returns win rate.

I am using Vuex and realistically I could put them in the Vuex store, however, I'm not sure if that's the best option so this is why I'm asking you guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's common practice to store such functions (called helpers) in files such as `helpers.js` or `utils.js`, which code could look something like this:

```js
export function winrate(wins, losses) {
    let games = wins + losses
    return Math.round(wins * 100 / games) + '%'
}
```

And then just import that helper in your component:

```js
import { winrate } from './path/to/helpers.js'

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    method() {
      console.log(winrate(1, 2))
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good option. Out of curiosity, would there be any difference performance wise between creating the function in a component and creating the function in the helper and then importing it?

Comment: I think it's not, because when you import that helper, it is always the same, so it's not creating over and over again. Instead of storing it in different components, each of them will have independent copy of it's method.